# Passing additional parameters in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can I pass additional parametrs to the component that I am transitioning to.

I have my routes.js as follows. I have declared two paths one for authorList and another for a particluar author's details.

```
var routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={require('./components/main')}>        
        <Route path="authors" component={require('./components/authors/authorPage')}/>
        <Route path="authors/:authorId" component={require('./components/authors/AuthorDetails')}/>
    </Route>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

And in my authorList Page there is function as follows.

```
showAuthorDetails(authorId) {            

    var myExtraParams = { key1 : val1, key2 : val2};
    hashHistory.push(`/authors/${authorId});     
}
```

Now In my AuthorDetail page I can get authorId by doing

```
this.props.params.authorId
```

But I also want to pass myExtraParams as an object but don't want to declare and pass it in the url.
I want to somehow access myExtraParams in the new component, perhaps say like by doing

```
this.props.params.myExtraParams
```

should give mt the object.  (Like the way it happens in Angular UI router by using stateParams)

How can I do that?

Comment: you could pass your params as props as shown in [this example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/passing-props-to-children)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try and change the structure of your routes a bit like so:

```
var routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={require('./components/main')}>        
        <Route path="authors" component={require('./components/authors/authorPage')}>
            <Route path="author/:authorId" component={require('./components/authors/AuthorDetails')}/>
        </Route>
    </Route>
);
```

Then in your authorList Page you could do

```
...
renderAuth() {
    if (this.props.children === null) {
        return(
            ....your default authorList
        )
    } else {
        return React.cloneElement(this.props.children || <div />, {myExtraParams: myExtraParams});
    }
}

render() {
    <div>
        {this.renderAuth()}
    </div>
}

showAuthorDetails(authorId) {            
    hashHistory.push(`/authors/author/${authorId});     
}
...
```

You should then be able to access this.props.myExtraParams in your authorsDetail page

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at this question. Maybe I am late and you already have got the solution but in case if not then you can simply do this by

```js
router.push({
  pathname: '/some-route',
  search: '?param=123',
  state: {
    additionalParam: 'value',
  },
})}
```

And on the receiving component side, you will get it as

```js
this.props.location.state.additionalParam
```

I hope it helps. In the case of any further help, feel free to let me know.

Thanks