# React Router v3 - How to declaratively pass & access additional metadata for child routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i have routes that look like this:

```
<Router history={syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)}>
  <Route path='/' component={Widget}>
    <Route path='/a' component={A} />
    <Route path='/b' component={B} expand />
    <Route path='/c' component={C} />
  </Route>
  <Route path='*' component={FourOhFour} />
</Router>
```

so, `Widget` renders `A`, `B`, or `C` as children.  Note that on `B` i've added my *own* prop, `expand`.  usually, `Widget` wraps children in some other padded DOM node.  when `expand` is truthy, i do not want it to be wrapped, and can handle it accordingly. **how can i go about achieving this goal**?

- in my `Widget` component, `props.routes` is a thing, but it contains an array of each route in the tree.
- in my `Widget` component, `props.route` is a thing, but it doesn't give me a reference to the matched child route.

  - its like i want a `props.route.child`, in order to sniff for `expand`

i envisioned something like this:

```
render () {
  const { children, route: { child: { expand } } } = this.props
  return (
    <div {...someOtherProps}>
      {expand ? children : <p id="padded-thing">{children}</p>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

i'm confident that this is a solved problem, albeit perhaps my strategy is off.

i did see a couple of near dupe threads, like [Passing additional parameters in React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431276/passing-additional-parameters-in-react-router), but given that im asking about a parent route seeing a to-render-child-route, i figured this is *different enough*.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be approaching it in a bit of a wonky way. React is generally a top-down, without a whole lot of action going the other way. Generally when you want to communicate back up, you pass in a callback or something.

You mentioned you don't want it to be wrapped, but I think having a Wrapper component would be the cleanest approach by far.

Something like this:

```
import { A, B, C } from './children';
import { Wrapper } from './wrapper';

const WrappedB = <Wrapper><B /></Wrapper>;

// ...
<Router history={syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)}>
  <Route path='/' component={Widget}>
    <Route path='/a' component={A} />
    <Route path='/b' component={WrappedB} />
    <Route path='/c' component={C} />
  </Route>
  <Route path='*' component={FourOhFour} />
</Router>
```

This let's you keep the top-down methodology without having to do some awkward parent-looks-at-child-then-renders-child-different approach.

Comment: doh! i submitted my remark early, thinking SO let me do snippets in comments.  anyway, i updated my original post w/ how i had actually envisioned it, still top down.  i think your approach is probably sufficient for me. thx :) i would, however, like to figure out a way to do that wrapping from within `Widget` vs at the route level